# How can I replace text after a specific word using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

I have a file named `.ignore`. In need to replace the `projdir`. For example:

```
ignore \..*
ignore README
projdir Snake
```

I need to replace Snake with, for example, "PacMan". I read the man page, but I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Search for a line that starts with `projdir`, and replace the whole line with a new one:

```
sed -i 's/^projdir .*$/projdir PacMan/' .ignore
```

`^` and `$` are beginning/end-of-line markers, so the pattern will match the whole line; `.*` matches anything. The `-i` tells `sed` to write the changes directly to `.ignore`, instead of just outputting them

Comment: If you use the long option for `-i`, which is `--in-place` then the example will be more self-documenting.

Comment: this doesn't really address the question in a general term, only in the specific example. to be fair, the example was also not general enough... check [my post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/599088/43667) for a more complete (and simpler) answer! and feel free to edit your answer accordingly. 

Comment: @cregox, welcome to SE. Posting just links and trying to evoke curiosity is not the style used here.

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to rewrite the entire line, using backreferences for the parts you want to keep:

```
sed -e 's/^\( *projdir  *\)[^ ]*\(.*\)*$/\1PacMan\2/'
```

Another approach is to rewrite that part of the line, but only if some other part matches:

```
sed -e '/^ *projdir / s/ [^# ]/ PacMan/'
```

Both examples rewrite the second whitespace-delimited word on lines where the first word is `projdir`.

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old post and it seems to be solved for you by the accepted answer, the actual question has not been answered. So for completeness and to help others:

Here the answer that actually matches for "Snake" and not for lines startting with "projdir"...

```
sed -r 's/(^.*)Snake/\1PacMan' .ignore
```

This replaces everything from the start of the line including "Snake" with everything before "Snake" + "PacMan". \1 stands for what is matched inside (). Everything after "Snake" remains untouched.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's:^projdir.*$:projdir PacMan:g' .ignore
```

^projdir is to find the line that starts with string projdir.
The .*$ there stands for the string after projdir in the line the same line.
The string projdir PacMan is the string with which we are replacing.
g is for global - to replace all such lines starting with projdir.
.ignore is the name of the file

Comment: Can you please extend your answer and clarify what is what?

Comment: Answers are much more useful if they include explanations for how and why a command or piece of code works.

Comment: I hope this is more useful after edit

Answer (score -1):

to answer the question in the title "how to replace text after a specific word using sed":

```
sed -i '/projdir$/!{s/Snake/PacMan/}' .ignore
```

makes wonders, as it doesn't expect the `Snake` will be in the same line as `projdir`! we all know  is never that easy to find.

`-i` will consolidate the change into the file

`$` is to match Snake even in the same line

wished i knew or remembered what exactly `!` and `{}` are for.

mostly learned from this amazing resource:

https://linuxhint.com/50_sed_command_examples/#s43

> The basic uses of `sed` command are explained in this tutorial by using 50 unique examples.

Comment: anyone mind to explain why this was not a good answer? what have i missed?

Comment: You missed the solution, does not work.

Comment: @timo thanks! indeed, it needs to be fixed...

Comment: Actually this solution has been very educative, and I'm using a variation of it in an actual issue.

Comment: @David thanks for the feedback! i'm glad the fix worked. 