# How to search and replace text in files but keep/reuse a certain part of text?

Tags: bash, text-processing, replace

I want to refactor many JavaScript files in many directories which contain access to an object in this format: `myObj.something.somethingElse` and I want it to be `myObj.getSomething(somethingElse)` how can I achieve this in shell?

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question adding real and testable examples, also add what have you tried so far.

Comment: This is a rather basic use case for `sed` and a concept known as a *backreference*. In the abstract, your question is similar to the one answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120046/233270). You may find other helpful duplicates by filtering on the `[sed]` tag and searching for `backreference`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace text after a specific word using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66878/how-can-i-replace-text-after-a-specific-word-using-sed)

Comment: The first object has `.something` and the second has `.getSomething`... is that correct or should the second also be `.something`? Or it is that, that you wish to replace, i.e. `s/.something/.getSomething/` Please clarify and give accurate examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably give *Sed* (the stream editor) a try using it's replacement command `s/regexp/replacement/`.